# Pandas make new columns from sub-string of another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to create new columns in pandas from sub-strings of another column.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = {'title':['Apartment 2 roomns, 40 m²', 'House 7 rooms, 183 m²', 'House 4 rooms, 93 m²', 'Apartment 12 rooms, 275 m²']}
```

I'm trying with regex to capture groups:

```
df['Name'] = df.title.str.extract(r'(^[a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
```

This one I got a good result. But I need a column with the number of rooms (without the word "rooms") and another column with the size without "m²". I tried:

```
df['Rooms'] = df.title.str.replace(r'(^[0-9]+)\s(rooms)', r'\1') #to capture only the first group, which is the number

df['Size'] = df.title.str.replace(r'(^[0-9]+)\s(m²)', r'\1') #to capture only the first group, which is the number
```

My output:

```
   Name      Rooms                         Size
0  Apartment Apartment 2 roomns, 40 m²     Apartment 2 roomns, 40 m²
1  House     House 7 rooms, 183 m²         House 7 rooms, 183 m²
2  House     House 4 rooms, 93 m²          House 4 rooms, 93 m²
3  Apartment Apartment 12 rooms, 275 m²    Apartment 12 rooms, 275 m²
```

Good output:

```
   Name      Rooms Size
0  Apartment 2     40
1  House     7     183
2  House     4     93
3  Apartment 12    275
```

Comment: I see a typo in the word `roomns`, so, I guess you need to account for this typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df["Rooms"] = df["title"].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*room', expand=False)
df['Size'] = df["title"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*m²', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                        title Rooms Size
0   Apartment 2 roomns, 40 m²     2   40
1       House 7 rooms, 183 m²     7  183
2        House 4 rooms, 93 m²     4   93
3  Apartment 12 rooms, 275 m²    12  275
```

The `(\d+)\s*room` regex matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits, and then just matches zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`) and then a `room` string.

The `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*m²` regex matches and captured one or more digits, and an optional string of a `.` and one or more digits, and then matches zero or more whitespaces and then a `m²` string.

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKHx7y/1) and the [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKHx7y/2).